# Size of subtree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Almost every online tutorial I see on the subject when it comes to finding the size of a subtree involves calling a recursive function on each child's subtree.

The problem with this in Python is that it overflows if you recurse past a few hundred levels, so if I theoretically had a long, linear tree, it would fail.

Is there a better way to handle this? Do I need to use a stack instead?

Comment: You can increase recursion limit with `import sys;
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000);`

Comment: If the tree is sufficiently large, it will overflow regardless. In my experience, you can't set recursionlimit arbitrarily high

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to use a stack instead?

Sure, that's one way of doing it.

```
def iter_tree(root):
    to_explore = [root]
    while to_explore:
        node = to_explore.pop()
        yield node
        for child in node.children:
            to_explore.append(child)

def size(root):
    count = 0
    for node in iter_tree(root):
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: The only difference between this and a recursive solution is that here, you are maintaining a stack instead of using the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror the recursive algorithm using a stack:

```
numNodes = 0
nodeStack = [(root,0)] # (Node,0 means explore left 1 means explore right)
while nodeStack:
    nextNode, leftOrRight = nodeStack.pop()
    if not nextNode: #nextNode is empty
        continue
    if leftOrRight == 0:
        numNodes += 1
        nodeStack.append((nextNode,1))
        nodeStack.append((nextNode.leftChild,0))
    else:
        nodeStack.append((nextNode.rightChild,0))
print(numNodes)
```

Some things to notice: This is still a **Depth-first** search! That is, we still fully explore a subtree before starting to explore the other. What this means to you is that the amount of additional memory required is proportional to the *height* of the tree and not the *width* of the tree. For a balanced tree the width of the tree is `2^h` where `h` is the height of the tree. For a totally unbalanced tree the height of the tree is the number of nodes in the tree, whereas the width is one! so it all depends on what you need :)

Now It is worth mentioning that you can make a potential optimization by checking if one of the subtrees is empty! We can change the body of `if leftOrRight == 0:` to:

```
numNodes += 1
if nextNode.rightChild: #Has a right child to explore
    nodeStack.append((nextNode,1))
nodeStack.append((nextNode.leftChild,0))
```

Which potentially cuts down on memory usage :)

Answer (score 1):

The stack would be the easiest non-recursive way of getting the size of the subtree (count of nodes under the given node, including the current node)

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def subtree_size(root):
    visited = 0
    if not root: return visited
    stack = [root]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        visited += 1
        if node.left: stack.append(node.left)
        if node.right: stack.append(node.right)
    return visited
```